# How to handle push notification in firebase

Tags: cordova, firebase, phonegap-pushplugin

I'm developing a real time chat application using firebase and phonegap,I need to handle push notifications when application is not running.Please guide me to handle push notification at my backend server for firebase changes.

thanks

Comment: This question is too generic. Please be more specific and post the code that is not working to you.

Comment: thanks @memecs for you quick response,Everything is working fine,I want to create push notifications on firebase data base changes when the client is not active means I want to inform user that he has new messages from someone when the application is not running,But I'm not getting relevant result of R&D for handling push notifications for firebase data changes

Comment: I'm sure @memecs knows what you mean when you say you want push notifications. Firebase _directly_ has nothing to do with push notifications. If your server is a node.js server, you can listen for changes in your Firebase instance and respond to those changes with push notifications. See how that answer is too generic? It's because your question is too generic. [Where does Firebase fit in your app?](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-03-25-where-does-firebase-fit.html) & [Firebase Work queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-work-queue)

Comment: As of today (May 19 2016) Google just rebranded GCM to Firebase Cloud Messaging and it offers this feature. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37336674/3032209) response for a more complete answer.

Comment: @XienLua If you figure it out please add the answer here

Answer (score 3):

Firebase directly has nothing to do with push notifications. If your server is a node.js server, you can listen for changes in your Firebase instance and respond to those changes with push notifications.

Read more :

1. [Where does Firebase fit in your app?](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-03-25-where-does-firebase-fit.html)
2. [Firebase Work queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-work-queue)

Comment: This is not true as of today. Firebase has a lot to do with push notifications and your app.